# Can I use a modified freezer to cool the hot side of a peltier element to reach very low tempetatures (-30°C)?

Tags: peltier

I'm quite new to this, so forgive me if I ask anything stupid, but I need some help and I hope that some of you here might be able to help me.

For a school project, I'm building a cloud chamber. The bottom of these chambers have to be very cold (-30 degrees C or -25 degrees F) . I have taken the compressor from an OLA freezer [image] and upgraded it. The copper plate on top reaches on average -7 degrees Celsius. Is it in any way a good idea to use an aluminium plate to make sure that the temperature is evenly spread across, place peltiers on top and add another aluminium plate as a top plate (with proper isolation and thermal paste ofc).

The plate is 50cm by 30cm. It would be okay if the peltier cooled area  is smaller. Should I try this (since my first attempt failed), could this even work, what peltiers should I use and what kind of temperature could I expect (I'm hoping for -30°C). I know I'm asling a lot, but any help would be appreciated. Thank you for reading.

Comment: Try and see what temp you get if you insulate the plate from the environment.

Comment: Check the data sheet of some peptides, you should be able to get near that temp without active cooling of the hot side